# What are the effects on others when a user is deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, users, community

A user may be involved in many types of contributions: Questioning, Answering, Voting, Flagging etc. What happens with these contributions after a user is deleted?

As this involves community, its obvious to assume that it would affect other users too (like reputation fluctuation etc). What exactly are the effects on others after a user is deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Delete option will delete the user account, anonymizes the account and will deletes any negatively voted posts they own. Any post with score 0 or above will not be deleted.

In this case, you may end up losing some rep - particularly if you've answered on a negatively voted questions and have answer with upvotes. You may also *gain* some rep, in case your post was downvoted. The voting will remain unchanged, since votes are anonymous by design.